# Mocked object not getting in my service?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-data-jpa

Mocked object not getting in service Here is my below code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classesExternalProviderMain.class)
@ActiveProfiles(ApplicationConstants.DEVELOPMENT_PROFILE)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    EmployeeService employeeService; 
    @Mock
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    String name;
    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    @Test
    public void testEmployee() {
        Mockito.when(employeeRepository.findByName(name)).thenReturn(getEmployee());
        List<Employee> resultedEmployees = employeeService.getEmployeeByName("mike");
    }
    private List<Employee> getEmployee(){
        //here is the logic to return List<Employees>
    }
}

public EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    employeeService.
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeByName(String name){
        List<Employee> employees =  employeeRepository.findByName(name);
        //Here I does't want to hit the real database so I have mocked it in testcase but I am getting empty list when I debug it. So can you please tell me what i did wrong in my "EmployeeServiceTest" to get List<Employee>
    }
}
```

So is there any additional logic  required in testcase to get the mocked object.

Comment: Is the declaration `String name;` in your test really like this or is-it a copy paste mistake?

Comment: Yes I have declared String name; really in my EmployeeServiceTest. It's not copy past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not mocking the call

```
employeeRepository.findByName("mike")
```

but you are mocking

```
employeeRepository.findByName(null)
```

since your variable `name` was never initialized. Change your code to:

```
Mockito.when(employeeRepository.findByName("mike")).thenReturn(getEmployee());
```